# Is dividing classes into defintion and implementation not purely for compile time purposes?

Tags: c++

Often I find it more cumbersome to define stuff in both headers and implementation files, when it works just fine to also write the implementation in the header file. What is the reason it is commonly done this way?

Comment: "to define stuff in both headers and implementation files" no, you declare it in headers, and define it in cpp files. But there is nothing that prevents you from `#include`ing everything, given that your machine to compile on has enough ram...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Technically, you define a class in the header file, and define its member functions in the source file (in the typical case).

Comment: @Angew: Usually you declare the member functions in the header file (within the definition) and define them in the cpp file. Then lines are blurred, but many people call the class-specifier the class definition, so here its an exception to be in the header, but then nothing is contributed in the cpp file.

Comment: Actually no matter how you look at it managing headers/sources is very annoying thing about C++, without comfortable IDE you spend hell of time on it and there's clearly a lack of good IDEs. Some development toward module system been made though, so maybe things will become better.

Comment: @PlasmaHH `class X { ::: };` is a defintition of class `X`, which contains the declarations (and/or definitions) of its members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate compilation is a big one.  When you have hundreds to thousands of cpp files the time starts to add up.  If everything is just implemented in the headers, you have to have a complete recompile each time a single class changes anything.

Another is the design/documentation perspective.  A user of your class should be able to get all the information they need from a header file, in a concise way, rather than have to look at the implementation.

Comment: I didn't know that compile time was still an issue today, but I can see why with a very high number of classes/subclasses. Thank you so much for pointing out some obvious reasons for me. :) It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Silverback Lightness Races in Orbit's answer discussing shared libraries is also a great point I overlooked.

Answer (score 8):

Practical reason: reducing compilation times, aiding the compiler, the ability to separate interface from implementation and therefore create shared/dynamic libraries that can be swapped out for different versions without recompiling the original program.

Actual reason: common sense.

Comment: And now we would like to talk about Java ... :)

Comment: @knivil: No, we really wouldn't...!

Answer (score 1):

Separating the interface from the implementation like this can be (and often is) quite useful (especially in larger projects) from a simple management perspective.

Write the header that specifies an interface, and other parts of the project can be written as if that component were complete, even though it's not actually implemented at all yet. In a typical case, you might write a header, then sometime later write a trivial mock implementation (e.g., that just returns saying the operation failed, without actually doing anything) and only later still write a real implementation that attempts to do anything useful.

Obviously the code won't *link* until you have at least a mock implementation, but other parts of the code can at least compile using only a header.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it is cumbersome, and apparently there's trend towards putting everything into the header file these days, probably as a result of people using languages like Java and C# where you declare and implement in one location.

However, the C++ compilation model is far more complicated than these languages, and the very nature of `#include` means that the compiler has to open, pre-process and parse every file you include. This can be a massive hit on a large project. Since the implementation of methods tends to change more that the declaration of the class you want to minimize the amount of re-compliation the compiler has to do it you change a method. By placing the code into a .cpp file it will only have to recompile this. If you put it into the header it would have to rebuild every file that included that header.

You can't avoid taking the rebuild hit if you add new methods to your class during development. However, you can avoid taking the hit if you add member variables by using the [pimpl (opaque pointer)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) pattern.